# facebook js sdk language

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

I've searched everywhere for answers, but just can't find them anywhere.

The Facebook javascript SDK, it's fairly simple to set the language, like this.

[From Tag Manager, setting the lang, in my case sv_SE for Swedish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhOuw.png)

All works fine with functionality. Except SDK refuses to output the language I have specified. When I look in my Chrome inspector, I can see the obvious answer. SDK says it operates in en_US despite the fact that I've set it in sv_SE.

[From Chrome inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Uizz.png)

There is also a difference in the version. My SDK is version 2.7 – inspector says 2.6 is running.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Can you possibly create a fiddle with the issue replicated or give us the site you get the issue on?

Comment: Most likely you put the code in more than one place …

Comment: @MathiasW Yes, of course. Sorry about that. The site is http://lindesvard.se

Comment: @CBroe Might be, but I don't think so. It's only in the GTM container. And according to Chrome inspector above, the script is inside the container.

Comment: The source code of the page you mentioned explicitly embeds the en_US version of the SDK, in version v2.6. `js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6&appID=1104138316327442";`

Answer (score 0):

The Swedish (sv_SE) SDK will never be injected on the page because a en_US SDK already exists. The script itself checks if there's a script with id `facebook-jssdk` - which of course exists in order to prevent multiple SDKs to be initiated.

So in order for you to be able to load the Swedish SDK you'll need to find and remove what loads the US SDK is loaded.

Comment: Yes, you were right. Thank you. I had the Simple Share Buttons Adder installed, and I did insert the same FB app ID into it, but yet it seems like the plugin blocks my language settings.